# How to determine if user already liked page(page of site not FB) with facebook like button?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-like

How to determine if user already liked page(page of site not FB) with facebook like button?

I need this to show different content for them in header of the site.

Thanks for help.

Comment: add a handler using javascript/jquery to the id/class of the fb like button

Comment: Is the like button in an `iframe` ?

Comment: it is in an iframe, i would imagine that facebook wants to prevent sites knowing if someone has liked it, because then you could force users before content is shown

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found this posibility in facebook graph API.

https://graph.facebook.com/me/likes

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/

Pity but this need to be authorized. Will try to find something else.

Answer (score 0):

If it is in an `iframe`, you can't access it programmatically because of [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).

Comment: i don't need to be this functionality in FB API, i just need some hack that can give me what i want. I figured out hot to determine if user registered on facebook, but i can't find how to determine if it already liked the site. So just asking maybe someone already find some possibility to do this.